# Changing fragments and saving web view states - going mad

Tags: android

Ive been trying to do this for the best part of a week and still have no luck.

I have an action bar with tabs (action bar sherlock) and Im switching through the tabs and changing fragments fine.

Each fragment has a webview and Im trying to save the state of the webview so the web page stays on the same page that the user left it on.

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class FragmentB extends SherlockFragment {

WebView myWebView;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   myWebView.saveState(outState);
   Log.w("///////", "onSaveInstanceState");

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   Log.w("///////", "onActivityCreated");

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w("///////", "onCreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, container, false);
     myWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);


     Log.w("///////", "onCreateView");


     if (savedInstanceState != null){

         myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
         Log.w("///////", "restore!");
     }
     else{
         Log.w("///////", "ELSE!");
         myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
         myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
         myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
         myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
         myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
         myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");   
     }



    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_b, container, false);
    return mainView;
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");

            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Any help would be great!

Comment: Anyone? Really getting fed up with Android

Answer (score 4):

The `onSaveInstanceState` method of a fragment will only be called when the parent activity needs to save its state; an example of this is when the parent activity is being destroyed/recreated during an orientation change. As a result, this method won't be called when you are simply replacing fragments or switching between them as tabs.

As a workaround for your particular case, you can save the state of your webview in a bundle in the `onPause` method and restore it in the `onActivityCreated` method:

```
    // Instance fields        
    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    /**
     * Save the state of the webview
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }

    /**
     * Restore the state of the webview
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (webViewBundle != null)
        {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
    }
```

See here for more information as well:

[How to save the state of a WebView inside a Fragment of an Action Bar](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-of-an-action-bar/?lang=en)

Comment: setRetainInstance(true) works fine. But I am loading different layout when changing orientation. How to achieve?

Comment: As a heads up to anyone going this route: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState(android.os.Bundle) `Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files if restoreState(Bundle) was never called.`